# Retrieve call Car entities that are in the Car entities Models collection based on model ids

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I want to do this query using nHibernate's QueryOver.

I have 2 entities:

```
Car
-id
- HasMany Models

Model
-id
```

I have this query but it doesn't work:

```
Session.QueryOver<Car>()
.JoinQueryOver(c => c.Models)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(m => m.Select(s => s.Id)).IsIn(models.Select(s => s.Id).ToList())
.ToList<Car>();
```

The sql looked like (from what I remember):

```
SELECT *
FROM Cars c
   INNER JOIN Models m ON (c.id = m.car_id)
WHERE 1 = 0
```

But I was looking for:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Cars c
   INNER JOIN Models m ON (c.id = m.car_id)
WHERE m.id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NH is confused by the superfluent `m => m.Select(s => s.Id)`. The root cause is, that the compiler chose the wrong JoinQueryOver overload which returns ICollection instead of Model. Use:

```
Session.QueryOver<Car>()
    .JoinQueryOver<Model>(c => c.Models)
        .WhereRestrictionOn(m => m.Id).IsIn(models.Select(s => s.Id).ToList())
    .ToList<Car>();
```